# recursively add new k:v pair to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, generator, yield

I have a nested dictionary where at any level I might have country information. I am applying a country normalisation function taken from a library which is called `to_code()` which spits out the ISO code of the string passed.

Here's my function:

```
def update_country(dictionary):    
   for k, v in dictionary.items():
       if 'country' in k:
           dictionary[k+"_iso"] = to_code(v, fuzzy=True)
           
       elif isinstance(v, dict):
           for result in update_country(dictionary=v):
               yield result
               
       elif isinstance(v, list):
           for d in v:
               if isinstance(d, dict):
                   for result in update_country(dictionary=d):
                       yield result
```

Imagine this nested JSON

```
JSON = {"company_code": "123456",
        "name": "Astrocom AG",
        "officers": [{"name": "Abigail Kaloomp",
                      "country_of_residence": "bvi"},
                     {"name": "EXPONET limited",
                      "address": {"address_line_1": "somewhere",
                                  "address_line_2": "somewhere_else",
                                  "country": "united kingdom"}}],
        "address": {"address_line_1": "somewhere",
                    "address_line_2": "somewhere_else",
                    "country": "italia"}}
```

when I run

```
from pprint import pprint
list(update_country(JSON))
pprint(JSON)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3417, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-39-4ac13e957742>", line 1, in <module>
    list(update_country(JSON))
  File "<ipython-input-38-8f467b1cdf1b>", line 7, in update_country
    for result in update_country(dictionary=v):
  File "<ipython-input-38-8f467b1cdf1b>", line 2, in update_country
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Which I understand - in fact, if instead of trying to insert a new key I updated the existing one by replacing the two lines below:

```
           dictionary[k+"_iso"] = to_code(v, fuzzy=True)
           # becomes
           dictionary[k] = to_code(v, fuzzy=True)  # overwrite existing value
```

then I do get a JSON where for the country keys I have an ISO code.

The thing is that I need both. Is this feasible at all using this logic or there is no way around changing the dictionary during iteration?

Comment: self explanatory "dictionary changed size during iteration". create a new dictionary this will solve your issue

Comment: simple solution is `for k, v in list(dictionary.items()):`

Comment: thanks! It worked!! If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to change a dictionary recursively:

```
JSON = {"company_code": "123456",
        "name": "Astrocom AG",
        "officers": [{"name": "Abigail Kaloomp",
                      "country_of_residence": "bvi"},
                     {"name": "EXPONET limited",
                      "address": {"address_line_1": "somewhere",
                                  "address_line_2": "somewhere_else",
                                  "country": "united kingdom"}}],
        "address": {"address_line_1": "somewhere",
                    "address_line_2": "somewhere_else",
                    "country": "italia"}}

def abbr(country_name):
    if country_name == 'italia':
        return 'IT'
    elif country_name == 'united kingdom':
        return 'UK'
    else:
        return '?'


def update_country(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        rv = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == 'country':
                rv[k + '_iso'] = abbr(v)
            rv[k] = update_country(v)
        return rv
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        rv = [update_country(v) for v in d]
        return rv
    else:
        return d

new_JSON = update_country(JSON)

# pretty print the new dictionary:
import json
print(json.dumps(new_JSON, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "company_code": "123456",
    "name": "Astrocom AG",
    "officers": [
        {
            "name": "Abigail Kaloomp",
            "country_of_residence": "bvi"
        },
        {
            "name": "EXPONET limited",
            "address": {
                "address_line_1": "somewhere",
                "address_line_2": "somewhere_else",
                "country_iso": "UK",
                "country": "united kingdom"
            }
        }
    ],
    "address": {
        "address_line_1": "somewhere",
        "address_line_2": "somewhere_else",
        "country_iso": "IT",
        "country": "italia"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the iteration to something like this:

1. Create all new keys (a dictionary comprehension would be `{f"{k}_iso": v for k, v in dictionary.items() if "country" in k}` )
2. Update your dictionary with the result of step 1
3. Do the for loop only with the conditions that yield something